# How do I make a texture readable programmatically

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, textures, jpeg

I'm trying to load a texture that I'm encoding to a jpeg and then serializing/sending as a byte array from a client to my server and then deserializing and applying the texture to an instantiated prefab. Everything seems to be working except at the end when I'm trying to apply the texture to my prefab. I'm getting the error:

> UnityException: Texture 'deer' is not readable, the texture memory can not be accessed from scripts. You can make the texture readable in the Texture Import Settings.
>   Player_Data+c__Iterator0.MoveNext () (at Assets/_Scripts/Player/Player_Data.cs:82)
>   UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (IEnumerator enumerator, IntPtr returnValueAddress) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/Coroutines.cs:17)
>   UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour:StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)
>   Player_Data:PrepareServerData(String) (at Assets/_Scripts/Player/Player_Data.cs:56)
>   PaintCraft.Controllers.c__Iterator2:MoveNext() (at Assets/_Scripts/ColoringBook/CanvasController.cs:221)

I know that I can make this readable in the unity editor, but since I'm doing all of this at runtime, how do I accomplish this?

convert texture to jpg

```
IEnumerator DoGetTexToBytes(Texture2D tex)
    {
        playerObj.texBytes = tex.EncodeToJPG(50);
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

assemble all player object data into byte array (including texture)

```
public void PrepareServerData(Texture2D texToSend, string typeToSend)
    {
        StartCoroutine(DoGetTexToBytes(texToSend));

        playerObj.texWidth = texToSend.width;
        playerObj.texHeight = texToSend.height;
        playerObj.texFormat = texToSend.format;
        playerObj.tranX = tran.x;
        playerObj.tranY = tran.y;
        playerObj.tranZ = tran.z;
        playerObj.type = typeToSend;
        Player_ID id = GetComponent<Player_ID>();
        playerObj.id = id.MakeUniqueIdentity();
        playerObj.strength = strengthToSend;
        playerObj.hitpoints = hitPointsToSend;

        Network_Serializer serialize = GetComponent<Network_Serializer>();

        // Send Data from Client to Server as many small sequenced packets
        byte[] bytes = serialize.ObjectToByteArray(playerObj);

        StartCoroutine(Network_Transmitter.instance.DoSendBytes(0, bytes));
    }
```

send bytes, receive on server and then instantiate a prefab with the texture:

```
[Server]
    public void InstantiatePlayerOnServer(PlayerObject playerObj)
    {
        GameObject go = Instantiate(Player_Controller.instance.serverAvatar, new Vector3(playerObj.tranX, playerObj.tranY, playerObj.tranZ), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;

        // go.transform.parent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;

        StartCoroutine(DoLoadRawTextureData(go, playerObj.texBytes, playerObj.texWidth, playerObj.texHeight, playerObj.texFormat));
    }

    [Server]
    IEnumerator DoLoadRawTextureData(GameObject go, byte[] texBytes, int texWidth, int texHeight, TextureFormat texFormat)
    {
        Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(texWidth, texHeight, texFormat, false);
        tex.LoadRawTextureData(texBytes);
        tex.Apply();
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        go.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = tex;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the read/write enabled flag on the image's import settings.

[image: Settings]

I don't think you can do this from code, unless you are writing an *Editor script* (which only works in the editor, not when published).

Comment: so how do i load a use a texture encoded as a jpeg as a texture on a prefab programmatically? i had to encode my texture as a jpg so that i could send it over the network quickly.

Comment: He asked from code not from the Editor. @greyBow See the duplicate

Comment: @programmer I looked through the other thread and unless I missed something it still doesn't explain how to take this duplicate texture and encode it as a jpg to reduce file size. i tried encoding the new texture that the script in the other thread created but I still got the same error is there any other way to encode a texture to jpeg and then read that back in programmatically?

Comment: @greyBow If you can't add "EDIT" to your question and add what you have done from the duplicate and where you are still getting that "readable" problem, it is impossible to help you. We will both end up wasting out time.